# "Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array" thrown during creating a custom EmailService in Postal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine, postal

I'm trying to configure Postal in class library project. To do this I need to configure custom EmailService. On Postal webpage there's a snippet for doing this:

```
// Get the path to the directory containing views
var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\Views");

var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));

var service = new EmailService(engines);
```

(See here: http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html)

Surprisingly, following error is thrown:

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException occurred   HResult=-2146233085
>   Message=Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the
>   array.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)   InnerException:

To be precise - it's thrown during adding `FileSystemRazorViewEngine` to `ViewEngineCollection`. `FileSystemRazorViewEngine` derives from `IViewEngine` and `ViewEngineCollection` derives from `Collection<IViewEngine>`.

And here's stacktrace:

> mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List.Insert(int
>   index, System.__Canon item) + 0x3e bytes
>
> System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.InsertItem(int
>   index, System.Web.Mvc.IViewEngine item) + 0x89 bytes

I can't figure out what causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same error. I suspect that Postal is built with slightly different version of System.Web.Mvc that the main project that causing ViewEngine incompatibility... But I only have production binaries of the postal...